# Initialising a single timer with redux-thunk in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, thunk

Currently, I am using a side effect for a timer that sends an update action to the store every 0.1s:

```
const Timer = ({ update, score }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        update()
    }, 100);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  })
  return (<p>{score}</p>);
}
```

Where is the best place to initialise the timer in incrementAsynch()?

```
function incrementAsync() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(update());
    }, 100);
  };
}
```

Should I keep it in useEffect?

```
const Timer = ({ update, score }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    incrementAsync()
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  })
  return (<p>{score}</p>);
}
```

If so how do I stop it? And does this create multiple counters?

Answer (score 0):

everytime you dispatch your **incrementAsync** a new interval starts but the old ones are not killed. so if you dispatch 3 times you will get 30 update actions per second.

Redux-Thunk is not very good for such cases. I would suggest that you try a middleware that is better suited for such problems.

The most important ones are
- [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/)
- [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/)

Both middlewares also have functionalities to cancel such timers